# Fade effect for <div> between pages

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can I create an effect like this (every time you click an option on the menu, you see a nice fading effect, that only occurs in the content of the web page not in whole page) see the example please:

http://www.wix.com/demone2/country_b_and_b

Please let me know If you know some jquery script that can do that effect or if you know other technique.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edited:

I added a class="transition" to the links in my menu and added a class="divTofade" to the div I wanted to give the effect. The link provide by Jojo works well but creates the effect on the whole page, just removing and changing some code I can give the fade but is not working as the example web I gave, is fading the -div class="transition"- to 0 and after that is redirecting to the other link and in the example while the -div class="transition"- is fading you can see in the background the content of the link you are redirecting.

```
$("a.transition").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 linkLocation = this.href;

$(".divToFade").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
});

function redirectPage() {
window.location = linkLocation;
};
```

Please help me :-)

Sorry for my english, not my native language.

Comment: Can you post your code here? It will provide no benefit for future users if you link to your site.

Comment: We assume that you are here after a lot of researches and no result but as i can see you are here in a way that you want us to code this for you :(

Please do your research and tell us what code you are trying and what error your are facing then we will help you but at least you must try your work yourself before assigning it to others :)

Comment: I'm not linking to my website and I don't think posting the code of my webpage will help. I just have something like this: <div id="menu">with some <a href=...></a> for linking other pages in my site</div><div id="content">content for that page</div> And the fade effect beteew pages for the id="content" is what I want.  Thank you anyway ;-)

Comment: I did a research before ask, in fact this is the first time I'm asking something (in my 20 years of life, lol) because I couldn't find solutions, all examples or scripts work with the whole page not only for some part of the web as the example I put. Thanks for your time answering but is not giving any help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can put some fadeIn and fadeOut effect for pages

```
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I know much better how to use those effects.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this effect here:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

Comment: Thank you Jojo, I can't believe I saw that page before and I couldn't create the script -.- for what I need it